# Вылетает ошибка в Lambda python

Tags: python, python-3.x, map, lambda

после выполнения строчки

```
a = map(lambda x: x*x, 5)
```

вылетает ошибка:

> TypeError: ' int object is not iterable

Объясните ,пожалуйста, почему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вторым параметром `map` должно быть значение итерируемого типа, т.е. что-то, что можно обойти поэлементно.
Например список, кортеж, строка (хоть ее элементы и не получится перемножить), и т.д.

```py
a = map(lambda x: x*x, [5])
```

Результатом будет объект типа `map`, который можно конвертировать в список:

```py
lst = list(a)
```

Если же вам просто нужно применить анонимную функцию к арументу, не связывая ее с именем, это можно сделать так:

```py
print((lambda x: x*x)(5))
```